# Meteor + React Email submission form works on computer not ios, why?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

Could someone tell me why this piece of code would work great on a desktop browser but not work on a mobile device? This is an email signup form in react+meteor and on the computer, I can click on this field and enter an email address. On an ios browser, I click on the field and it pops open a dialog box for me to type something in, but I can't see any letters I type get added into the text box. I copied the structure of this from meteor base: https://github.com/themeteorchef/base

```
export class AddEmail extends React.Component {
  addEmail(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    let email = this.refs.email.value.trim();

    insertEmail.call({
      email
    }, (error) => {
      if (error) {
        Bert.alert(error.reason, 'danger');
      } else {
        this.refs.email.value = '';
        Bert.alert('Email Added!', 'success');
      }
    });

  }

  render(){
    return(
        <Col xs={12} className="input-group">
          <form className="newEmail" onSubmit={this.addEmail.bind(this)}>
          <input className="btn btn-lg indexEmail"
                 ref="email"
                 name="email"
                 id="email"
                 type="email"
                 placeholder="Enter your email address for beta access" required />
          <button className="btn btn-info btn-lg indexSubmit" type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </Col>
    )
  }
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: What about it isn't working?

Comment: Sorry, on a computer it works perfectly. On an iphone, I click on the field and the keyboard comes up but no letters get entered into the text box as I type and when I press enter it didn't register any of the keystrokes.